# VB.NET Get text in between multiple Quotations

Tags: vb.net

i need some help.

i need to get there text file value on Quot ("") on multi textbox1, textbox2, textbox3. but can only get on value (first value on textbox1)

now a time i just get one value (firt value on Quot)

text file (2.txt):
 C:\contexture\img2itp.exe "\mynetwork\1.png" "\mynetwork\2.png" "148"

code vb:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\test\2.txt")
    Dim line As String
    ' Read the stream to a string and write the string to the console.
    line = sr.ReadToEnd()
    Dim s As String = line
    Dim i As Integer = s.IndexOf("""")
    Dim f As String = s.Substring(i + 1, s.IndexOf("""", i + 1) - i - 1)

    TextBox1.Text = f
```

thanks for a help :)

Comment: Simply use a Regex Match: `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1` or the simpler version: `"(.*?)"`

Comment: Are you trying to strip the command arguments from an application call statement? Those will be space delimited and do not always have to be enclosed in quotes. But if you just want the ones that are, split the string, using a space as the separator, and then compare the items in the array for the ones that start and end with a double quote.

Comment: @Mike I wouldn't recommend split for such operations it isn't reliable.

Comment: @Mederic Actually you are right, if the pathnames contained spaces, they would be fragmented, good catch.

Comment: @Mike No problem took me a while to get away from split to regex more often haha

Answer (score 0):

### Regex Match

**What Is Regex :**

> A regular expression is a pattern that the regular expression engine attempts to match in input text. A pattern consists of one or more character literals, operators, or constructs.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Here we could consider two Regex Expressions to solve this problem a simple version and a more complex creating capture groups.

**Simple one :**

```
"(.*?)"
```

Here is the explanation: https://regex101.com/r/mzSmH5/1

**Complex One :**

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"(.*?)"
```

Here is an explanation: https://regex101.com/r/7ZMVsB/1

---

### VB.NET Implementation

This would be a job for a [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) which would work like this:

```
Dim value As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\test\2.txt")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, """(.*?)""")
' Loop over matches.
For Each m As Match In matches
    ' Loop over captures.
    For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
        ' Display.
        Console.WriteLine("Index={0}, Value={1}", c.Index, c.Value)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: how can i take the 3 result in 3 defferent textbox?

Comment: @pakeerathanarumainayagam We are not here to code the whole program for you if you don't event know how to write a string to a textbox I suggest you start learning your basics before copy pasting: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/index.htm